# Sending values to custom dialog

Tags: android, android-intent, customdialog

Ask...

how to send value to custom dialog , and then after the show on the custom dialog is actually transported to another activity ?

this is myy code :

[image]

Comment: What do u mean by send value to custom dialog?

Comment: I suggest next time use English in naming variables and post the actual code and not a picture. Thanks

Comment: So, here it is. eg I have 2 activity , the activity can first send value to alertdialog or custom dialog, and then from alertdialog delivered more value to the second activity

Answer (score 0):

Inside in your `onClick`

```
Intent in = new Intent(this,ActivityB.class)
in.putExtra("key",etIdEktp.getText().toString());
in.putExtra("key2",etKodeVerifikasi.getText().toString());
startActivity(in);
```

In your `ActivityB.java`

```
String val  = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
String va2  = getIntent().getStringExtra("key2");
```

Comment: yes , if the transmit from there to another activity I understand. 

but before being sent to another activity , I want to take the first value to the custom dialog

Comment: If I understand correctly what you mean; Use the same code above but without "key2" since you only need the first Edittext.

Comment: So, here it is. eg I have 2 activity , the activity can first send value to alertdialog or custom dialog, and then from alertdialog delivered more value to the second activity

Comment: Then use etIdEktp.setText("Your text here");

Comment: yes , because my program is working with mysql database , etIdEktp here for retrieving values ​​from the table , then etVerifikasi can be entered and checked for correct or not logging

Comment: It is odd to me on why you are using EditText rather than TextView since the purpose of that view is for displaying. It would be helpful if you Rephrase the question add more details. Thanks

Comment: Yes, could be
Edit Text etIdEktp but it could also later in the same locker Text View or perhaps with visiblity = gone on Edit Text. I think now as where to take the value of the activity to alertdialog